# Python Pygal: Dynamic svg width

Tags: python, svg, pygal

I try to comiple a punch card graph using pygal in which I have to draw a large amount of x-tics (>400).

Right know pygal stacks the various x-tics over each other so that no label can be read any more. Instead to this behavior I would like that pygal extends the width of dynamically and thereby compiles a svg document with a large width.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Can you post your code and a screenshot of the output?
If you have already solved this, please consider answering your own question as it will be very instructive to others.